# rails join table issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 2 tables `Product` and `Ecr`

my models 
Product model

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ecr_products
    has_many :ecrs,through: :ecr_products
 end
```

Ecr model

```
class Ecr < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ecr_products
  has_many :products, through: :ecr_products
end
```

and EcrProduct model

```
 class EcrProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ecrs
   belongs_to :products
end
```

when i trying to do `Product.last.ecrs` getting `NameError: uninitialized constant Product::Ecrs`

where is mistake?

Comment: `belongs_to` typically uses a singular name. Although I wonder if that could lead to an error like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
belongs_to :ecrs
belongs_to :products
```

to

```
belongs_to :ecr
belongs_to :product
```

The singular version should be used when using belongs to.